# FileNotFoundException for System.Drawing V4 when migrating from TFS2010 to TFS2012. Exception Code 0xE0434F4D

Tags: tfsbuild, filenotfoundexception, system.drawing, resgen

I have a large solution developed in VS2005 .Net 2. We migrated from TFS2010 to TFS2012 (keeping the Framework as .Net v2). All work fine in IDE, build and install, but when program is executed, get the following Problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: myProgram.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.5
Problem Signature 03: 550f8264
Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 53a12268
Problem Signature 07: f15
Problem Signature 08: 3
Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version:      6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:           2057
```

TFS2010 build server is Windows XP SP3 x86.

TFS2012 build server is Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

I have migrated the Framework  to .Net 4 and all works fine, but unfortunately some clients requite .Net 2.

1. Using WinDbg gave me the following:

   ```
   Problem Signature 04 gives us where the error originated, mscorlib.
   Problem Signature 07 gives us the methodDef, which we can use to get the methodDesc “702b8c10” => “System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)”
   Problem Signature 08 gives us the Offset so when I do a dump of the IL, I get “ldarg.0” at offset 3.
   ```

As far as I can see, argument 1 of System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName i.e. the string is 0, hence the FileNotFound exception, but it doesn't tell me the file name.

2. Using FusionLog gave me the following:

It successfully loads System.Drawing v2 but then also tries to load v4 which fails (I have checked that none of the projects reference any .Net v4 assemblies).

```
** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (30/03/2015 @ 14:45:05) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\myProgram.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = HOST1\Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Common Files/myProgram/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = myProgram.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Common Files/myProgram/System.Drawing.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Common Files/myProgram/System.Drawing/System.Drawing.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Common Files/myProgram/System.Drawing.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Common Files/myProgram/System.Drawing/System.Drawing.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Here's an excerpt from Procmon:

```
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\myProgram.resources\1.0.0.5_en_0a4a2ad97614f98d  PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\myProgram.resources\1.0.0.5_en_0a4a2ad97614f98d    PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\myProgram.resources\1.0.0.5_en_0a4a2ad97614f98d PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\en\myProgram.resources.dll  PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\en\myProgram.resources\myProgram.resources.dll  PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\en\myProgram.resources.exe  PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\en\myProgram.resources\myProgram.resources.exe  PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Drawing\4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a   NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\System.Drawing\4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a    PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\System.Drawing.dll  NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\System.Drawing\System.Drawing.dll   PATH NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\System.Drawing.exe  NAME NOT FOUND
CreateFile  C:\Program Files\Common Files\myProgram\System.Drawing\System.Drawing.exe   PATH NOT FOUND
```

As you can see it tries to load myProgram.resources.dll and fails, then tries to load Framework v4 files, which made me look at the resource files.

3. mscorlib.resources.dll is installed by language packs of .Net and by Silverlight. Tried installing Silverlight as our TFS2010 build server had this, but didn't work.
4. [This article]:["Could not load file or assembly System.Drawing or one of its dependencies" error on .Net 2.0, VS2010 and Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190885/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-or-one-of-its-dependencies-erro) says the System.Drawing error is due to a resource file bug in VS.
   I have tried the suggested solution:

Edit the top line of the Image stream: AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w TO AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4w
None of the resource files in my solution has the erroneous top line in the image stream "j00LjAuMC4w"

Also checked all the .resx files for 4.0.0.0 version but they were all 2.0.0.0

5. Here's the Crash Mini Dump:

Dump Summary

```
Dump File:  WER6229.tmp.mdmp :     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WER6229.tmp.mdmp
Last Write Time:    16/04/2015 10:46:17
Process Name:   myProgram.exe : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\myProgram\myProgram.exe
Process Architecture:   x86
Exception Code: 0xE0434F4D
Exception Information:  An exception came from the CLR
Heap Information:   Not Present

System Information
------------------
OS Version: 6.1.7601
CLR Version(s): 2.0.50727.5485

Modules
-------
Module Name Module Path Module Version
----------- ----------- --------------
myProgram.exe   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\myProgram\myProgram.exe 1.4.2015.12
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll   6.1.7601.18247
mscoree.dll C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll 4.0.40305.0
kernel32.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll    6.1.7601.18409
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll  6.1.7601.18409
advapi32.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll    6.1.7601.18247
msvcrt.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll  7.0.7601.17744
sechost.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll 6.1.7600.16385
rpcrt4.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll  6.1.7601.18532
sspicli.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll 6.1.7601.18719
CRYPTBASE.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTBASE.dll   6.1.7600.16385
mscoreei.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll  4.0.30319.18408
shlwapi.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll 6.1.7601.17514
gdi32.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll   6.1.7601.18577
user32.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll  6.1.7601.17514
lpk.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll 6.1.7601.18177
usp10.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll   1.626.7601.18454
imm32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll   6.1.7601.17514
msctf.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll   6.1.7600.16385
mscorwks.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll  2.0.50727.5485
msvcr80.dll C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6229_none_d089f796442de10e\msvcr80.dll  8.0.50727.6229
shell32.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll 6.1.7601.18429
ole32.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll   6.1.7601.17514
profapi.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll 6.1.7600.16385
mscorlib.ni.dll C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\38bf604432e1a30c954b2ee40d6a2d1c\mscorlib.ni.dll    2.0.50727.5485
mscorsec.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll  2.0.50727.5483
wintrust.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll    6.1.7601.18205
crypt32.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll 6.1.7601.18277
msasn1.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll  6.1.7601.17514
comctl32.dll    C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll 5.82.7601.18201
cryptsp.dll C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll 6.1.7600.16385
rsaenh.dll  C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll  6.1.7600.16385
imagehlp.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll    6.1.7601.18288
ncrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll  6.1.7601.18714
bcrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll  6.1.7600.16385
bcryptprimitives.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll    6.1.7600.16385
userenv.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll 6.1.7601.17514
gpapi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\gpapi.dll   6.1.7601.18711
cryptnet.dll    C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll    6.1.7601.18205
Wldap32.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll 6.1.7601.17514
SensApi.dll C:\Windows\System32\SensApi.dll 6.1.7600.16385
uxtheme.dll C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll 6.1.7600.16385
mscorjit.dll    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll  2.0.50727.5467
myProgram.Engine.dll    C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\myProgram.Engine\1.0.0.5__0a4a2ad97614f98d\myProgram.Engine.dll    1.4.2015.12
System.ni.dll   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\908ba9e296e92b4e14bdc2437edac603\System.ni.dll    2.0.50727.5485
System.Drawing.ni.dll   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\836e10dfd0811b303553216f5cb092ef\System.Drawing.ni.dll    2.0.50727.5483
System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\1453d9e9a4989833ef3db4b22549ba1a\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll    2.0.50727.5483
myProgram.Designer.dll  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\myProgram.Designer\1.0.0.5__0a4a2ad97614f98d\myProgram.Designer.dll    1.4.2015.12
myProgram.UI.dll    C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\myProgram.UI\1.0.0.5__0a4a2ad97614f98d\myProgram.UI.dll    1.4.2015.12
DevComponents.DotNetBar.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\DevComponents.DotNetBar\5.8.0.0__7eb7c3a35b91de04\DevComponents.DotNetBar.dll   5.8.0.0
version.dll C:\Windows\System32\version.dll 6.1.7600.16385
apphelp.dll C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll 6.1.7601.17514
```

The Mini Crash Dump gave me the Exception Code 0xE0434F4D.

- Tried [this idea][[program name].exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300572/program-name-exe-has-stopped-working) running myProgram as admin but no help.
- [This blog]http://blog.toxa.de/archives/38 (also dealing with .Net 2) gave me the idea remove the icon from the SplashScreen. Which affects the error raised. Instead of getting the 1 error as described above you get 3 errors with the continue option.

  6. From the build log:

I saw MSBuild from Framework v4 was used

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "F:\Builds\59\Platform\myProject_BugFixing_CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" /m:1 /nr:False "@F:\Builds\59\Platform\myProject_BugFixing_CI\BuildType\TfsBuild.rsp"
```

- Have tried adding Set ToolsVersion = 2.0 and TargetFrameworkVersion = v2.0 in each of the project files and ToolsVersion="2.0" in TFSBuild.proj.
- Ran Framework v2 MSBuild from command line:

  - None of the switches (/m:1 /nr:False "@F:\Builds\59\Platform\myProgram_BugFixing_CI\BuildType\TfsBuild.rsp") are recognised.
  - After removing these, build fails on Line 7 of TFSBuild.proj, as SolutionRoot is not recognised.
  - If I hard code this, the build fails on C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\ Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets Line 359 also referring to SolutionRoot. It says there is an invalid child element _SolutionRoot in the namespace.
  - This suggests to me that MSBuild v4 is the correct version and must also be used by TFS2010 build server.

    7. TFS Build.log revealed different ResGen versions used in build:

I replaced the TFS2012 build server ResGen with the TFS2010 build server exe and ran a build successfully, that made no difference.

```
    TFS2010 – Path of ResGen used: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\ResGen.exe
    This is v3.5.30729.4507 and dated 19/03/2010

    TFS2012 – Path of ResGen used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin\Resgen.exe
    This is v2.0.50727.42 and dated 23/09/2005
```

[This post][MSBuild cant find resgen.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840912/msbuild-cant-find-resgen-exe) suggests setting

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

to the same value as the setting ProductionVersion in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A
```

it was v8, but this didn't work.

8. Using IlSpy on myProgram.exe (both versions) to decompile the code show two tree structures in which the decompiled .cs files are identical but the binary .resource files are different (both size & content).

In particular binary editing reveals that at the tail of mainform.resources are the lines (there are of course other diffs):

```
System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d
```

in the old TFS2010 exe, vs

```
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

in the new TFS2012 exe.
This means that the new build is using .Net 4 binary serialisation; the old is using .Net 2 binary serialisation.

A quick decompile of ResGen shows it’s a pretty simple program that:

- Parses args
- Reads resources from .resx files
- Uses a binary resource writer to write the output file

I suspect that the two versions are pretty similar since there should be no real need to change (both are actually flagged as .net2/AnyCPU).

What’s more interesting is that the binary serialiser used comes from mscorlib therefore the new build must be using the .Net 4 mscorlib 
(but the build log says it’s v2

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
FusionName = mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

) despite the fact that ResGen is actually a .Net 2 binary – this would explain why overwriting the the ResGen.exe version tried in point 7 above had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the TFS2012 build server from:
Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 => Windows 7 x86